# Transpose 'Sheet1'!A1 with B1!A1

Tags: excel

I have the sheet, say "StackOverflow", and a value in cell A1, "Hello", that I want in my sheet "Test" at a specific cell.

I know that I could type ='StackOverflow'!A1 to get the cell value. The thing is that I do not always want to use the sheet "Stackoverflow" and instead want it to be like

```
 =B1&!A1
```

where B1 holds a value that corresponds to a worksheet in my workbook.

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the INDIRECT function :

```
=INDIRECT("Stackoverflow!A1")
```

or

```
=INDIRECT(B1&"!A1")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDIRECT(B1 & "!" & A1)
```

Note that the above allows you to place any cell reference in `A1`.

If you want it to always refer to `A1`, then use

```
=INDIRECT(B1 & "!A1")
```

Answer (score 1):

=INDIRECT(B1&"!"&A1) would do this.